# Background Image Repeats in Iphone

Tags: css

I used background-attachment:fixed; for my stylesheet and on the desktop it shows correct as one background image.

However that is not the case with iphone as the background repeats on their browsers.

How can I code my css so that is shows as 1 background image instead of repeats of the same image?

http://clarissagriffin.com/test1

Answer (score 0):

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kubik/1/)

```
background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
```